# boost interprocess shared mutex and boost interprocess condition variable for shared mutex

Tags: c++, boost, mutex, interprocess, condition-variable

Boost version - 1.47
I can not find boost::interprocess::interprocess_sharable_mutex, but it looks like it is forward declared. Is this really supported ?

I can see that boost::interprocess::interprocess_upgradable_mutex is forward declared and it is also defined as well. However, I am not able to find a corresponding condition variable with which I can use this mutex. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I was just looking for this myself and came upon this question and [this discussion](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2011/02/66033.php) on the Boost Users mailing list that effectively says, "No, you can't." `boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition` can only be used with the standard mutex. :(